# Cannot use Log4J2 with Wildfly

Tags: logging, wildfly, log4j2, jboss-modules

I'm working on a JEE application which uses log4j2 for logging. I'm trying to deploy it on Wildfly 15, but I can't get it to log properly, stating

`Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...`

Here's what I did:

- I've added log4j2-api.jar as a system module to Wildfly (system/layers/base/org/apache/log4j2/main) with a simple module.xml.
- I've taken the code from https://github.com/jboss-logging/log4j2-jboss-logmanager, built a JAR, and added that as a system module to Wildfly (system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j2/logmanager/main), with a module.xml that defines a provided service:

```
    <provides>
        <service name="org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider">
            <with-class name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.JBossProvider" />
        </service>
    </provides>
```

- I've added org.apache.log4j2 and org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager as dependencies to the org.jboss.logmanager module, stating `services="export"` on the latter.

I'm aware of https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-482, but I can't seem to draw the right conclusions from it.

Can anyone help or knows how to diagnose further what's going on here?

---

For full reference, the module.xml for org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager looks like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8" name="org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="log4j2-jboss-logmanager.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j2"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
    </dependencies>
    <provides>
        <service name="org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider">
            <with-class name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.JBossProvider" />
        </service>
    </provides>
</module>
```

…although i've tried both referencing org.jboss.logmanager as a dependency of org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager and the other way around.

The module.xml for org.apache.log4j2 looks like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.log4j2">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="log4j-api.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Comment: What does your `module.xml` files look like? They should look something like https://github.com/jamezp/wildfly-core/commit/cabcf5c71ef2815c8442d7eda6d1e63930adf248#diff-a20c1b8d1398b3f2b8d531a1d04fd8c1 and https://github.com/jamezp/wildfly-core/commit/cabcf5c71ef2815c8442d7eda6d1e63930adf248#diff-85d8592708d89a62bd8844cb0429edc2.

Comment: Why would the org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager module depend on org.jboss.logmanager, instead of the other way around? From where would the org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager module be referenced? That seems to be the part that I don't understand.

Comment: Added both module.xml above and tried both log4j2.logmanager depending on logmanager and the other way around, with the same result.

Comment: Because the `org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager` requires the `org.jboss.logmanager` not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager` module.xml you don't need that `<provides/>` definition. Other than that your module.xml files look correct.

Next you'll need to define both the `org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager` and `org.apache.log4j2` modules on your deployment. If you're using a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` it would look something like the following for a WAR:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j2"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

One minor note is those should probably live directly under the `modules` directory and not the `modules/system/layers/base` directory. Though it doesn't break anything that is really meant for modules provided by the server.

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine as long as I start Wildfly from the command line, using standalone.bat. As soon as I use a service wrapper (Tanuki), it breaks down. I don't have a deployment structure descriptor, and I'm using an EAR. No matter which way I tweak classpath, jboss.modules.system.pkgs, global-modules (standalone.xml), module definitions and dependencies, I can't get this to work. What happens is that the MSC service thread loads EJBs from JARs in the EAR, and in its context it can see the log4j2-api, but not the JBossProvider. Any ideas?

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `jboss.modules.system.pkgs`. You're best bet is either a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or the `Dependencies:` entry in your manifest file.

Comment: With the global-modules make sure you try with `meta-inf="true"` on the `org.jboss.log4j2.logmanager` module too.